# Quicksort algorithm, a few little clarifications needed

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I'm studying basic array sorting and am struggling just a little bit to fully understand it's logic. I understand the recursion, meaning splitting an array to two arrays on each side of a pivot, and then continuing partitioning each of these sub-arrays until an array of just one element is reached.
What I don't always completely understand is the implementation of the while loop itself.

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaAlgorithmsQuicksort/article.html

Here I've encountered an implementation that chooses the middle element as the pivot. I understand the pivot can be any element, whether it's the first, last, any random element or an element specifically chosen for maximum efficiency.
With the middle element as pivot for some reason I find it more intuitive to understand.

```
  while (i <= j) {
        // If the current value from the left list is smaller than the pivot
        // element then get the next element from the left list
        while (numbers[i] < pivot) {
            i++;
        }
        // If the current value from the right list is larger than the pivot
        // element then get the next element from the right list
        while (numbers[j] > pivot) {
            j--;
        }

        // If we have found a value in the left list which is larger than
        // the pivot element and if we have found a value in the right list
        // which is smaller than the pivot element then we exchange the
        // values.
        // As we are done we can increase i and j
        if (i <= j) {
            exchange(i, j);
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
```

This is the relevant part.

1) Why do we increase i and decrease j only if the i element is smaller than the pivot or the j element is larger than the pivot? Why not also when it's equal? 
If an element is equal to the pivot, it's fine where it is, since it doesn't matter which side of the pivot it ends up in, so why can't we move on increasing/decreasing? 
I've tried doing it by the way and as I expected the end result wasn't sorted and I didn't understand what went wrong even after debugging step by step.

2) Am I right in saying that, excluding edge cases, upon exiting the external loop, i = j +1? Always? And that one of these elements, i or j, has the value of the pivot we used? But which one and why?

```
// Recursion
    if (low < j)
        quicksort(low, j);
    if (i < high)
        quicksort(i, high);
```

3) What I would have expected here, instead of passing on low to j and i to high,
is:
assuming pivotIndex is the index of the pivot after the loop ends,

```
quicksort(low, pivotIndex - 1);
quicksort(pivotIndex + 1, high);
```

because pivotIndex is right where the pivot should be, it's his final position.
So I would love an explanation for that too, please.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before getting into the corner cases, let's take a look at the normal operation of the algorithm. A sample starting array is shown below. The pivot value is 33. The indexes `i` and `j` are shown above the array.

[image]

The `while` loops update `i` and `j`. `i` moves forward to the first value greater than the pivot. The values in green (25 and 8) are less than the pivot, and are in their final positions. The value in red (49) is greater than the pivot, and is in its final position.

[image]

Now, the numbers 51 and 14 are swapped, and `i` gets incremented, `j` gets decremented.

[image]

The `while` loops update `i` and `j`. Note that `j` didn't move.

[image]

After the exchange (pivot values shown in yellow)

[image]

One more time through the `while` loops and `i` has moved past `j` which completes the partitioning. You can see that all of the values from `i` to the end of the array are either red (greater than the pivot) or yellow (the pivot). And all value from `j` to the beginning of the array are either green (less than the pivot) or yellow.

[image]

So in this case `i=j+1` and one of the indexes (`i`) points to the pivot.

Now let's look at an array where `i` doesn't end up equal to `j+1`, and neither `i` nor `j` points to the pivot value. The starting array (using 33 as the pivot again):

[image]

After the `while` loops:

[image]

After swapping 2 with 50:

[image]

After the `while` loops:

[image]

Notice that both `i` and `j` stopped at the pivot value. So after the exchange, the situation looks like this:

[image]

I believe that answers questions 2 and 3. It is not always true that `i=j+1`, and it is not always true that one of the indexes points to the pivot. Also, the algorithm already excludes the pivot from the recursive calls in some cases.

You *could* modify the algorithm to exclude the pivot in more cases, but that seems risky and messy. And there's not much benefit unless the array size is fairly small. In production `qsort` implementations, the algorithm switches to a different method (e.g. selection sort) when the array sizes get small.

On to question 1. What happens if the while loops are modified to allow values equal to the pivot? The answer is that one of the indexes can run off the end of the array. Here's an example (using 33 as the pivot):

[image]

All of the values are greater than or equal to the pivot, so the `j` index is going to run right off the end of the array:

[image]

Depending on what's in memory ahead of the array, the `j` index could keep on going for a very long time, and even crash the program. This could be fixed by comparing `j` with zero
`while(j>0 && numbers[j] >= pivot)` but that extra check slows down the algorithm. The amount of time that you save by not stopping at the pivot is not nearly as much as the amount of time wasted doing the extra check in the `while` loops.

Answer (score 1):

1. Let's consider your suggestion, step by step:
   Base conditions:
   `arr = {1, 20, 3, 4, 20, 70, 80, 90, 100}`
   `i->1` `j->100` `pivot = 20 (the 2nd one)`
   Iteration 1:
   `while (numbers[i] <= pivot)...` => `i->70`
   `while (numbers[j] >= pivot)...` => `j->20 (2nd one)`
   `if (i <= j)...` => `false`

   Iteration 2:
   `while (i <= j)` => false
   So this makes the array already sorted. (which is not true).

   While in the current algorithm, in the 1st iteration, `i -> 20 (1st one)` and `j -> 20 (2nd one)`, and a swap occurs. What matters here is not the swap itself but the fact that `i` did not become greater than `j` on the 1st iteration
2. What if `i=j` in the `if` statment? that would execute both `i++` and `j--` making the difference between them 2. if that case does not occur then yes `i=j+1` and you can't tell if it's `i` or `j` equals to pivot because then it would depend on the location of the pivot in the array.
3. This is exactly what's happening here. Upon exiting the external loop, `i` will be equal to `pivotIndex + 1` and `j` will be equal to `pivotIndex - 1`; either `i` or `j` will also include `pivotIndex` itself. You can work it out step by step using pen and paper and see what's going on.

Hope that helped

Answer (score 0):

1. If you include equality in the first loop, it will not stop if no elements are larger than pivot. Using strict inequalities is an easy way to ensure the algorithm stops.